# Shell script programming : "bad number" error

Tags: linux, shell

I am writing a simple shell script and I am having a strange error about "bad number". Here is my code :

```
status=0
maxRetries=3
retryCount=1
while [[ status == 0 ]] || [[ retryCount -le  maxRetries ]]
do
    ....
    retryCount=$((retryCount+1))
done
```

As far as I see, I have properly declared maxRetries and retryCount as integers, so I don't see why it complains about bad number on the while statement. 
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status`, `retryCount` and `maxRetries` are strings, not numbers. You want to expand those parameters with the `$` sigil. Alternatively, you could use arithmetic expressions, which do not require the sigil.

```
while (( status == 0 || retryCount < maxRetries ))
```

Comment: `status`, is also missing a `$`